# Getting 'No carrier' with connman on Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: wireless, connman

I'm using `connman` 1.33 on Ubuntu 17.04.

I've just installed it by running `sudo apt install connman`. This command also removes NetworkManager.
Right after installing, I was able to connect to my WPA2 protected wifi network and get an IP address by running:

```
connmanctl
> scan wifi
> services
> agent on
> connect wifi_<hash>
```

This was 3 minutes ago. I then rebooted, and executed the commands again.

Now, `connmanctl` shows me an error after entering `scan wifi`:

```
Error /net/connman/technology/wifi: No carrier
```

How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem after a fresh installation of Debian Bookworm through WiFi. WiFi was reserved always. After several searches finally I found `dhclient` which started `wpa_supplicant`. It is part of `isc-dhcp-client-ddns` package. After removing it and a reboot everything works fine.